# Comparing objects in HashSet

Tags: java, collections

I'm making a 2D game that has a stars in it. I decided to create constructor in class named Star that gives random coordinates.

```
public Star(){
    super(0,0);
    x = randomX.nextInt(maxX - minX + 1);
    y = randomY.nextInt(maxX - minY + 1);
}
```

Then, in other class I put them in HashSet

```
Set<Star> star = new HashSet<>();

public Set<Star> generateStars(){
    while (star.size() < numberOfStars){
            star.add(new Star());
    }
    return star;
}
```

Of course, I have render and tick methods but I think it's not worth to paste them. My lecturer told me that there can be same stars and to prevent that I should use identity function using hashcodes. Can someone help me figure that out ? I imagine that this function should check if the hashcodes are the same and if it's the case it should return only one value that way we will add 1 object instead of 2 into the HashSet. Am I right ?

Comment: What do you mean by same stars? If the criteria for equality is same coordinates, just generate hashcode and equals depending on the coordinates. If not, just choose the appropriate criteria for equality and override hashcode and equals depending on it.

Comment: Your constructor has some problems with it, it would probably be better to use the same RNG. Also your y coord is using the `maxX` variable.

Comment: Yes, same I mean coordinates.

Comment: You need to create a hashCode and equals method. You can generate these using your IDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Overriding the `hashCode()` method alone in your `Star` class will not work** you will have to override the `equals()` method.

See the following code where we don't override the `equals()` method:

```
class Star {
    int x, y;

    public Star(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(x, y);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Star s1 = new Star(0, 0);
        Star s3 = new Star(0, 0);
        Star s2 = new Star(31, -31*31);
        Set<Star> set = new HashSet<>();
        set.add(s1);
        set.add(s2);
        System.out.println(set.size());
    }
}
```

This will print 3 (instead of 2 what you might expect).

The reason for this is that the add method of `java.util.Set` compares 2 objects based on `equals()` method and not based on `hashCode()` method.

In the above code for the `Star` class, if you add the `equals()` method the output will be 2 now. For your reference the you can override the `equals()` method as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object startObject) {
    if (this == startObject) return true;
    if (startObject == null || getClass() != startObject.getClass()) return false;
    Star star = (Star) startObject;
    return x == star.x &&
            y == star.y;
}
```

So why do you need to add `hashCode()`?

1. As you are using `HashSet` the add method behind the scene will call the `equals()` method and will also call `hashCode()` to decide the bucket in which the new object should be put. To maintain the contract of `hashCode()` and `equals()` Both should be overridden.
2. When ever you override `equals()`, it is recommended to override `hashCode()` also. (Vice-versa is also true). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265637/2346131) link for details.

**Contract for `hashCode()` and `equals()`**: If for two objects say `o1` and `o2`, `o1.equals(o2)` is `true` then hash of `o1` and `o2` `should` be same.

Make sure that you understand this properly, from the above statement it is not implied that if the hash of 2 objects are same, then `o1.equals(o2)` should return `true`. **It can be possible that for 2 objects, their hash is same but the `o1.equals(o2)` returns `false`**

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), what `Object`'s `hashCode()` method guarantees.

See [this](https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-hashcode-and-equals-in-java) link to get more detailed information about this topic.

Comment: "This will print 3 (instead of 2 what you might expect)." -> it is printing 2 only

Answer (score 2):

In java, when adding an object to a HashSet, the add method uses the 'equals' method, which is part of the Object class (however you can override it) in order to determine if the set already contains the object you are trying to add, see : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

However, if you are overriding the equals method then you should also override the hashCode method, this is very well explained in the following post : [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

If you are going to follow this advice, I would also advise using ApacheCommonsLang [EqualsBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) and [HashCodeBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html) if your lecturer allows it as they provide a solid implementation based on the rules laid out in the book 'Effective Java' by Joshua Bloch

To override the equals method in your Star class, you want to think about the criteria that make two star objects equal. From your example this might be that both of them have the same x and y co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

you can override hashCode() method from Object. So, in your Star class, add:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    in hash = .... //make your hash code about the coordinates of your star.
    return hash;
}
```

so, when you place a new star with the same co-ordiante in the hash map, it will overwrite the previous start with the same co-ordiantes if already present in the map.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `hashCode` and `equals`.
the code should be like this:

```
  public static class Star {
    int x, y;
    public Star(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return x * 1000 + y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (obj instanceof Star) {
        Star s = (Star) obj;
        return this.x == s.x && this.y == s.y;
      }

      return false;
    }

  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    HashSet<Star> set = new HashSet<Star>();
    set.add(new Star(1, 1));
    set.add(new Star(1, 1));

    System.out.println(set.size());
  }
```

**note:** choose the suitable hashcode function for you. I assumed here that y should always be less than 1000.

Comment: It's ok to have conflicts within the hashset. do you gurantee that String.hashcode return different hashcodes for every possible strings in the world? that's why we need equals method!!

Comment: please suggest different implementation for the hashcode method?

Comment: I added a different implementation for hashcode, but I still don't guarantee that all possible objects will have different hashcodes.

Comment: Producing distinct hash results for unequal objects will improve the performance of hashed collections. You should aim to produce an unequal hash if the objects are unequal. This allows containers to uniformly distribute collections of unequal instances across all possible hash values. I suggest some hash of form: `h(star) = m * star.x + star.y + c` for some scalar `m` and offset `c`. The offset `c` is important for distinguishing the star `(0,0)` from `null`. The values used for the constants are arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse as your editor just right-click on the editor pane, go-to source then generate hashcode() and equals() pick the parameters you would like to consider. You will get an autogenerated function.